# Can I multiply vectors of different lengths?

Tags: r, vector, vector-multiplication

```
v1 <- c(1,2)
v2 <- c(3,4,5,6)
```

Is there a way to multiply these two vectors such that the result is a vector dim(1,3)
such as `(11,14,17)`

This is analogous to all possible dim(1,2) multiplication combinations such as
`(1,2) %x% t(3,4)`, `(1,2) %x% t(4,5)`, `(1,2) %x% t(5,6)`

It seems so simple, have looked and no luck.

Comment: Aren't there 6 possible combinations rather than 3?

Answer (score 7):

Create a 2-row matrix:

```
> rbind(v2[-length(v2)],v2[-1])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    5
[2,]    4    5    6
```

Then it's just matrix multi:

```
> v1 %*% rbind(v2[-length(v2)],v2[-1])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   14   17
```

and subset if you want a vector:

```
> (v1 %*% rbind(v2[-length(v2)],v2[-1]))[1,]
[1] 11 14 17
```

Answer (score 3):

Use subsetting and `cbind` to create a matrix of your combinations, then apply across the rows of this with your multiplication.

```
apply(cbind(v2[-length(v2)],v2[-1]),1,function(x) v1%*%x)
[1] 11 14 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to James' answer, but maybe simpler:

```
sapply(1:(length(v2)-1), function(j) sum(v1*v2[j:j+1]))
```

Since you're only multiplying vectors (aka 1-by-N matrices :-) ), there's no need to dive into the matrix ops.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
na.omit(filter(v2, rev(v1)))
```

You could also use `embed`:

```
apply(embed(v2, 2), 1, FUN='%*%', rev(v1))
```